# Jetpack compose Animation handling when new items are created

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation

I have the following code where I pass a list of colour balls, and each ball is animated based on `enabled` status. Now, the issue is when I again invoke the same function with a new list of balls, the y-axis value is the same as the previous list of values, and post animation is completed, which means new items are also shown at the bottom of the screen.

```
@Composable
fun MultipleBalls(
    enabled: Boolean = false,
    onSizeAvailable: ((maxWidth: Int, maxHeight: Int) -> Unit)? = null,
    generatedBalls: List<ColorBall>
) {
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        onSizeAvailable?.invoke(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight)
        generatedBalls.forEach {
            CircleBox(ball = it, constraints.maxHeight, enabled)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CircleBox(ball: ColorBall, maxHeight: Int, enabled: Boolean) {
    BoxWithConstraints {
        val animatedOffset: Float by animateFloatAsState(
            if (enabled) {
                maxHeight.toFloat() + ball.radius
            } else {
                ball.offset.y
            },
            animationSpec = snap(ball.animateTime),
            label = "animate_offset",
        )
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
        ) {
            drawCircle(
                color = ball.ballColor,
                radius = ball.radius,
                center = if (enabled) ball.offset.copy(y = animatedOffset) else ball.offset,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do so that when the new list is passed, each ball starts from the initial value and animates to the screen end?

Following is the color ball class.

```
data class ColorBall(
    val radius: Float,
    val offset: Offset,
    val ballJustClicked: Boolean,
    val ballColor: Color,
    val animateTime: Int,
)
```